# Is it possible to create anonymous type in LINQ extension methods in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

Is it possible to create anonymous type in LINQ extension methods in C#?

For example LINQ query.i.e.

```
var CAquery = from temp in CAtemp
 join casect in CAdb.sectors
 on temp.sector_code equals casect.sector_code
 select new
 {       
     //anonymous types
     CUSIP = temp.equity_cusip,
     CompName = temp.company_name,
     Exchange = temp.primary_exchange       
 };
```

Is the same behavior supported for LINQ extension methods in C#?

Comment: Obviously, if you want to pass these anonymous objects between methods, you'll probably run into trouble.

Comment: Like [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx)?

Comment: @spender I can easily use anonymous types in different places in code. What do you mean?

Comment: When you return or pass an anonymous object, you can either pass it as object or as a generic type T. In both cases, all knowledge of the interface to the object is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean "when using the extension method syntax"? If so, absolutely. Your query is *exactly* equivalent to:

```
var CAquery = CAtemp.Join(CAdb.sectors,
                          temp => temp.sector_code,
                          casect => casect.sector_code,
                          (temp, casect) => new
                          {       
                              CUSIP = temp.equity_cusip,
                              CompName = temp.company_name,
                              Exchange = temp.primary_exchange       
                          });
```

The C# language specification sets out all the translations in section 7.16. Note that in this case, as your `join` clause was *only* followed by a `select` clause, the projection is performed within the `Join` call. Otherwise (e.g. if you had a `where` clause) the compiler would have introduced *transparent identifiers* to keep the two range variables (`temp` and `casect`) available, via a new anonymous type which just kept the pair of them in a single value.

Every query expression is expressible as non-query-expression code. Query expressions are effectively a form of preprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

something like this maybe...

```
var CAquery=CATemp.Join(.....)
                  .Select(temp=>new
                           {       
                           CUSIP = temp.equity_cusip,
                           CompName = temp.company_name,
                           Exchange = temp.primary_exchange       
                           });
```

Answer (score -1):

The LINQ query you have shown *is* an extension method.  It will simply be transformed by the compiler into a call to the `Join` extension method.  You can create an anonymous type anywhere you can create *any* type, which include inside any extension methods.